# F# FSharp.Literate formatted code snippet does not display correctly (.css & .js?)

Tags: html, f#, mono, xamarin, literate-programming

I'm trying to use FSharp.Literate to produce html pages. I'm working in Xamarin using Mono 4.5. I want to turn basic `*.fsx` scripts into html. I am using the simple [script example from the documentation](http://tpetricek.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/literate.html) for tests. The script I wish to turn into html looks like this.

```
(**
# First-level heading
Some more documentation using `Markdown`.
*)

(*** include: final-sample ***)

(** 
## Second-level heading
With some more documentation
*)

(*** define: final-sample ***)
let helloWorld() = printfn "Hello world!"
```

I used the built in NuGet manager to download `FSharp.Formatting`. It also installed `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2` and `RazorEngine`

Based on the example in the documentation, I wrote the following script to turn the above example into html. I'm using the html template from the original FSharp.Formatting on github.

```
#I "bin/Debug/"

#r "FSharp.Literate.dll"
#r "FSharp.Markdown.dll"
#r "FSharp.CodeFormat.dll"

open System.IO
open FSharp.Literate

let source = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
let baseDir = Path.Combine(source, "html/")
let file = Path.Combine(baseDir, "demo.fsx")
let output = Path.Combine(baseDir, "demo-script.html")
let template = Path.Combine(baseDir, "template.html")

Literate.ProcessScriptFile(file, template, output)
```

The process runs and it does produce an html file. However, the F# code does not tokenize. Instead of nicely formatted code, I get the example below. Am I missing something obvious?

**Edit**:

Based on Tomas' comment below, I found the problem with the .css and .js files. 
The template I used had `href="{root}/content/style.css" /> <script src="{root}/content/tips.js"`

The {root} tag was the reason it could not find the css and js files.
Changing that to `href="content/style.css" /> <script src="content/tips.js"` solved the problem

[image: screen shot of html]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the library actually produced the correct HTML. As you can see at the end of the file, the content that should appear in the tool tips (information about the type of `helloWorld` and `printfn`) is there.

The problem is likely that the generated HTML file does not correctly reference `tips.js` and `style.css` that defines the formatting for the HTML and script to pop-up the tool tips.
These two files should be included in the NuGet package (together with the default templates), or you can find them [on the project GitHub](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting/tree/master/docs/files/content).

Comment: tips.jp and style.css are there in the project. Do I need to edit the html template so that it can find them?

Comment: @AndreP. You can either modify the template, or copy the two files to a `content` folder in the directory where the `html` files are produced (the default location expected by the template is `content/tips.js` and `content/style.css`.

Comment: Indeed the problem was with the html. I just happened to use the `template.html` file in the sample. it includes the following html `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{root}/content/style.css" />
    <script src="{root}/content/tips.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` The `{root}` tag was why it couldn't find the `*.css` and `*.js` files. When I switched to another template, it all worked out correctly

Comment: Ah `{root}` is a parameter that can be set by using the `replacements` parameter of `ProcessScriptFile`. See: http://tpetricek.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/literate.html